# Node can't find the module - Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have ASP.NET background. I'm trying to understand the "route" logic of Node.js using MVC logic in ASP.NET. For example in my global.js, there is an AJAX call to /users/userlist (I don't know what it is, it's controller in MVC). I'm trying to reach that controller using below code, but I get this :

> GET http://localhost:3000/users/userlist 404 (Not Found)

What should I do to get rid of this? Thanks.

This is app.js (complete) :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest2');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});


app.use('/', index);
app.use('/userlist', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is users.js (complete) :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/*
 * GET userlist.
 */
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('userlist');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.json(docs);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is global.js :

```
$.getJSON( '/users/userlist', function( data ) {

    // For each item in our JSON, add a table row and cells to the content string
    $.each(data, function(){
        tableContent += '<tr>';
        tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowuser" rel="' + this.username + '">' + this.username + '</a></td>';
        tableContent += '</tr>';
    });

    // Inject the whole content string into our existing HTML table
    $('#userList table tbody').html(tableContent);
});
```

This is index.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I run this code, I get this :

> GET http://localhost:3000/users/userlist 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Get what? After sentence "When I run this code, I get this :" there's nothing ;)

Comment: I made an edit: > GET http://localhost:3000/users/userlist 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Try going to localhost:3000/userlist

Comment: @JayGould it gave 404

Comment: Did you try and debugging steps?  Did you see if any of your middleware was getting hit at all on that request?  Are you exporting the router properly in users.js?  Are you starting your server properly?  Are you loading the browser page from `http://localhost:3000`?  The general structure of what you show is correct if you have implemented each step appropriately, but you don't show us enough code to know for sure.  For example, you don't show starting your server, you don't show exports from users.js, you don't show defining `db`.  You don't show how the browser page itself is loaded.

Comment: I'm thinking that `app.use('/', index);` might be a bit too greedy since it may match all routes.  What is happening in index.js?

Comment: Is this all of app.js?  Or is this a shortened version?  We may need to see all of the code.

Comment: @jfriend00 I posted all of the code of index.js. I posted all functional code of app.js. I can post all of it if you want me to. I think server is working properly and yes I'm loading the page from the address you told me. I can provide anything else than I posted. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide all of app.js and all of users.js?

Comment: I have posted both. Thank you.

Comment: Weirdly, I restarted mongodb and it worked...

Comment: I also moved userlist code to index.js

Comment: In app.js change `app.use('/userlist', users);` to `app.use('/users', users);` and put it before `app.use('/', index);` for good measure

Comment: @TylerKirby That worked as well... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inlucde the following line all code i app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
// other code below
```

Comment: We are likely looking at a shortened version of the code.  That must already be in the file or the server code wouldn't even run because the reference to `express()` and `express.static()` would throw.